# When we use singular form of Property when we refer to multiple properties?

Tags: word-usage, plural-forms, singular

In some advertisement websites (such as Gumtree, Zoopla or Friday AD) they use *Property* to indicate the category name (as a group).

However they use plural forms for any other categories such as *Cars*, *Jobs*, *Services*, etc.

So why exactly and when we use singular form for *Property* word if we refer to multiple Properties (as category)?

Is usage of *Properties* word instead as category name is wrong in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sense of 'a thing or things that are owned by sb; a possession or possessions', (Oxford ALD) *property* is freqently used as a non-count noun.

In the sense of 'a building or buildings and the surrounding land' (OALD), *property* is used as a count noun.